# bitwise or and assignment

Tags: c, bit-shift, bitwise-or

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMVALS 6
#define SIZE 5
#define MAX 31

int main () {

   int vals = 0;

   short curVal, idx = 0;


   for(; idx < NUMVALS; ++idx) {
      scanf("%d", &curVal);

      vals = (vals << SIZE) | curVal;
   }

   printf("%d", vals | curVal);

   return 0;
}
```

This is some code I am working on. It is supposed to store 6 integers each in the range from 0 to 31, so each gets a space of 5 bits. For some reason it is not working. When I make the assignment to vals in the loop, it seems to only be storing the current value read in into vals. Do you see what might be going wrong?

Comment: Not checking the return value of `scanf()` is always dangerous.

Comment: At this point, I am just assuming that I am putting in 6 integers, and not worrying about incorrect input. Is there some other reason I should worry about the return value of scanf?

Comment: You need to check the return value of all functions in C.  Otherwise how will you know if something is wrong?

Comment: Try changing `int vals` to `long`. You need a 32 bit number to store the integers.

Comment: @JohnZwinck on certain occasions, checking errno. :-P

Comment: @alphagamma since this is a play/practice program, no, no reason here to check the return value of scanf. At a wrong input you just restart the application. **But** you should get into habit of checking all functions that might fail. To this end even in programs like this you should do that just so that it comes to you as a second nature when you write bigger programs.

Comment: ok, I will consider checking scanf return value. the program seems to be working now that i am using %hd in the place of %d in the scanf call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A halfway decent compiler will tell you:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘short int *’
     scanf("%d", &curVal);
```

You need to use `%hd` to scan a `short`, or (in this case better) change your variable to `int`.

If you're using GCC, add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your compilation command.  It would have caught this for you.

Answer (score 1):

First change type of `vals` to `long int`, so it will be able to store at least 30 bits and type of `curVal` to `int` to match the scanf call.

Then make sure you only assing 5 bits to `vals`:

```
vals = (vals << SIZE) | ( curVal | 0x1F );
```

And when you print the last value, use the *and* bitwise operator, since you only want to keep the least significant 5 bits.

```
printf("%ld", vals & 0x1F );
```

Answer (score -1):

Mr. Alpha, if you want to store 6 values the for loop must run for 6 times.so you need <= in condition as  idx<=NUM....
And one more thing is you are not storing at any place,through out the program.

Comment: The loop runs six times because idx starts at 0, so it runs through the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, for a total of six runs. Also, the storing is happening with the line that says: vals = (vals << SIZE) | curVal;